# Dynamically finding TypeScript object values through passed in parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

not sure if the title is misleading or actually is asking what I want:
I am trying to get an Object's element value, but the tricky thing is that the element's name is being passed in through a function...

Here is a simplified sample of my code, hope it's clear what I am trying to do

```
export interface logItem {
   id: string
   procedure: string
   units: string
   serviceCode: string
}

function calculateTotalsBasedOnType(
   logItems: Array<logItem>
   totalsType: string
): totals {
   ... log.totalsType ...
}
```

what's the way to go about finding the specific log's element value through the passed in totalsType?

Here is an example method for this

```
calculateTotalsBasedOnType(logItems, 'serviceCode')
```

the line `log.totalsType` should give me the value of the `serviceCode` from the `log`

Comment: What is the value of `totalsType`? Is it one of `id`, `procedure`, `units`, or `serviceCode`? Also, which element in the array should it get?

Comment: it can either be procedure or serviceCode..

Comment: the element that it is trying to get is the value of the totalsType: calculateTotalsBasedOnType( log, 'serviceCode')

Comment: Can you put sample in your question?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi just did, hope that helps

Comment: There's no way to get "the value of the `serviceCode` from the `log`", since `log` is an array of objects, each with a `serviceCode`. In other words, `log` is something like `[ { id: 1, procedure: 'procedure', units: 12, serviceCode: 'abc' }, { id: 2, procedure: 'erudecorp', units: 21, serviceCode: 'cba' } ]` (I don't know what the actual values are obviously).

Comment: If you want to get the property whose name is stored in `totalsType`, that's answered in [Dynamically access object property using variable](/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes that's my fault, I did not show that `log.serviceCode` is a single item from that array

Comment: How do you expect to get from `Array<logItem>` to `totals`?

Comment: @HereticMonkey i tried that, it still does not liking the `totalsType` being a string. I actually figured it out, I needed to make the `totalsType` to a string literal

Comment: `type TotalsTypeValue = 'serviceCode' | 'procedure'`

Answer (score 0):

In order for typescript to understand that the passed in parameter is a element key of an object you need to make that parameter a string literal type

```
type TotalTypeValue = 'serviceLine' | 'procedure'

function calculateTotalsBasedOnType(
   logItems: Array<logItem>
   totalsType: TotalTypeValue
)
```

now when trying to do `log.totalsType` it will look for the value of totalsType to be one of the elements in the `log`

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty vague on the subject what exactly you're trying to achieve. But if I got it right, to get the type of the inner field from array you'll have to use [keyof operator and lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types):

```ts
function calculateTotalsBasedOnType<T, K extends keyof T>(
   logItems: Array<T>,
   totalsType: K
): T[K] {
   return logItems[0][totalsType] // just random element from the source array
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W44L7W)